# Объединение малых файлов в один большой

Tags: delphi

Есть много мелких файлов(флаги стран). они по мене надобности загружаются в TImage. Требуется из всех этих файлов создать один, да так, что бы из него можно было достать одну картинку и загрузить в TImage, не извлекая все файлы на диск.

Искал в Гугле... но просто не знаю, как у него спросить... Как не спрашивал - либо про прикомпиляцию ресурсов к экзешнику выдает, либо про запаковку и последующее извлечение файлов на диск...

В общем, что бы было так, как работают современные, допустим, игры... в которых ресурсы запакованы в большие файлы

Comment: Как насчет подойти к вопросу с другой стороны и воспользоваться TImageList?

Comment: Нет, не пойдет.
Мне нужно периодически обновлять этот большой файл через интернет

Comment: Возьмите исходник старой юниксовой утилиты ar и посмотрите (tar -- её наследник). Возможно в той, что используется сейчас, много наворотов, так что найдите старый (только не забывайте про виндовые хохмы с текстовым/двоичным режимами ввода-вывода). А вообще в OS/360 и наследниках даже был специальный метод доступа к библиотечным файлам. Их функционал тут избыточен (не требуется обновление).

Comment: Не вижу как одно препятствует другому, ну да ладно... Тогда один большой файл + таблица смещений.

Comment: >прикомпиляцию ресурсов к экзешнику
Еще бывает компиляция ресурсов во внешнюю библиотеку.

Comment: Тогда уж «линковку».

Comment: во, то что нужно! ко внешней библиотеке!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть варинт попроще - все флаги собрать в одном файле.

Загрузить в TBitmap, например, используя LoadFromFile.

А потом используя CopyRect, копировать в TImage.

Comment: Собственно, это и делает image list

Comment: а вот это интересно!
я уже написал, почему TImageList не подходит.

Comment: @metalurgus, обоснуйте. Я не вижу как обновление всех флагов через интернет ломает логику предоставляемую image list или самодельный велосипед предложенный в ответе.

Comment: погуглил на счет TImageList. И нашел статью, в которой описано, как сохранить ресурсы из компонента(TImageList) в файл, и обратно. Буду пробовать

Comment: Я чтото запутался что вас больше интересует как из одного большого файла вытаскивать маленький кусок рисунка который вас интересует или как этот файл обновлять через интернет.

Comment: я что-то тоже запутался))
У меня есть много маленьких файлов(флаги стран), которые загружаются в компонент TImage по мере их надобности. Я хочу объединить все эти файлы в один для того, что бы их(флаги, уже в одном файле) было проще обновлять через интернет.
Как обновить файл через интернет я знаю...

Comment: 1 вопрос как объеденить

Самый легкий способ залить все файли в TImageList а потом нажать в редакторе TImageList-а кнопку Export. И у вас получится 1 Файл в котором все флаги красиво рядышком лежат.

2 вопрос как это использовать
Вариантов куча все выше перечисленное подойдет и LoadFromFile в TBitmap и один большой файл + таблица смещений. Вобшем какой нравится.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно просто создать архив. Самый простой способ - найти обычный zip архиватор (или 7z) и паковать ресурсы. Как не странно, но именно так поступает большое кол-во производителей игр. Компоненты можно поискать на torry.net.

Способ два. Создать такой архив самому. Самый простой вариант - это записывать так 4 байта маркер, дальше 2 байта длина имени, потом само имя, потом 4 байта размер данных (картинка).
А читать это все через TFileStream. TImage/TJpeg умеют загружать себя с потока (stream) и при этом вычитают сколько им нужно.

Если нужно найти ресурс по имени, то получится такой алгоритм:
 - прочитали маркер
 - прочитали длину названия, вычитали его
 - вычитали размер
 - если это подходящее название - просто вычитываем картинку
 - если нет, то делаем seek на известное кол-во байтов и повторяем процедуру

Comment: Для Delphi есть хорошая свободная библиотечка для работы с архивами разных форматов - [Abbrevia](http://tpabbrevia.sourceforge.net/).